# Subdomains for Umbrella Companies?

Tags: subdomain

Are lots of Subdomains a good idea?

We are an events company, all our websites are currently all separated from each other on their own domain - so we have our main site for our company and a site for every event we run (9 total). All sites have to be updated regularly and a lot share similar information - contact page, staff etc.

Im looking into simplifying this, using subdomains seems the answer but I have mixed views on whether its the best way of organising this. With our Host provider we pay $9 a month on essential package for 10 sites when we could pay $18 a month for one 'premium' package and subdomain the events under it (10 limit though).

Is there a better solution to this or am I on the right track?

Answer (score 0):

You may reorganize your code from subdomains to unlimited number of subfolders once per event.

```
http://yourdomain.com/folder1
http://yourdomain.com/folder2
....
http://yourdomain.com/folder999
```